# POST request data containing list of dicts

Tags: python-requests, ckan

I'm trying to call an API that wants a list of dicts for one value.
I build a dict that looks similar to this:

```py
dataset = { 
  'name': 'somename',
  'note': 'somenote',
  'extras': [{'first': 'entry'}]
}
```

I'm including this in my POST:

```py
r = requests.post("URL_ENDPOINT", data=dataset, headers=headers)
```

Checking the actual `dataset` dictionary shows the list of dicts correctly.

```py
{'name': 'somename', 'note': 'somenote', 'extras': [{'spatial': 'test'}]}
```

**But** checking the requests object, `r.text`:

```py
 ... "extras": "first", "type": "dataset"}}, ...
```

It looks like the list of dicts is being munged in some fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to inject `json` parameter instead of `data`

```
r = requests.post("URL_ENDPOINT", json=dataset, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m less than smart - the API wanted the dict to use “key”: and “value”:

I did try a JSOn package and it looks like it would work also. Thank you very much!